# How can I embed these anchors correctly within my coding?

Tags: html, css

I have read this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Linking_to_another_section_on_the_same_page) on how to use anchors to achieve what I'm asking. However, I'm totally lost. I was wondering if someone could show me what I'm looking for and explain it.

**Q1**
For my website, when the user clicks on the webpage "Contact" on the navigation bar, I want the user to be force-scrolled down to section three on my homepage webpage. I was using something like this before `<section id="contact-me" class="contact_section"></section>`. However, how can I embed this within my HTML section3 and still keep the class "section3".

**Q2**
How can I link my arrow down on section1 to go to section 2? Here is my attempt but that brings you to a page I want it to force the user to scroll down to section 2 within my webpage.`<a href = ".section2"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>`

**Q3**

How can I How can I link my arrow down on section2 to go to section 3?

How can I How can I link my arrow down on section3 to go back up to section 1?

Below is my coding.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #4D5061;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #4D5061;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.nav.navbar-nav,
.nav.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#logo {
  padding-top: 2vh;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 95vh;
}

.section1 {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.section2 {
  //height: 95vh;
  background-color: #A59E8C;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.section3 {
  //height: 95vh;
  background-color: #A59E8C;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.fa-angle-down {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.fa-angle-up {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.footer {
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: #4D5061;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0:
}

h1 {
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Your Brand Name"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<section class="section1">
  <div class="hero"></div>




  <a href=".section2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

</section>
<section class="section2">



  <a href=".section2"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

</section>

<section class="section3" id="section3">

  <a href="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

</section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

<footer>
  <div class="page">
    <h1 class="footer">Copyright © 2017 Liam Docherty's Site. All rights reserved.</h1>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: you need to reference an id instead of a class in your link, like `href="#id"`

Comment: from what I understand, you can't do exactly what you want. `<a>` links inside the page are based on the `id` attribute, not the a CSS selector. You can keep the class as `.section2`, but you must also add an `id` attribute of the same thing in order to make the `href="#section2"` portion work as expected.

Comment: I managed to work out everything apart from section 3 going back up to section 1.


   `<section id="contact_me" class="section3">
 
  <a href = "#section1"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

    </section>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in my comment, links that reference another part of the page do so by the element's `id` attribute. You can keep the same classes on your `<section>` tags, but they **must** have an `id` attribute.

To solve your question of having section 3 go back to section 1, I just gave section 1 an ID and set the link in section 3 to point to that.

Feel free to ask any clarifying questions

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #4D5061;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #4D5061;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.nav.navbar-nav,
.nav.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#logo {
  padding-top: 2vh;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 95vh;
}

.section1 {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.section2 {
  //height: 95vh;
  background-color: #A59E8C;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.section3 {
  //height: 95vh;
  background-color: #A59E8C;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.fa-angle-down {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.fa-angle-up {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.footer {
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: #4D5061;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0:
}

h1 {
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Your Brand Name"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<section id="section1" class="section1">
  <div class="hero"></div>




  <a href="#section2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

</section>
<section id="section2" class="section2">



  <a href="#section3"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

</section>

<section class="section3" id="section3">

  <a href="#section1"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

</section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<footer>
  <div class="page">
    <h1 class="footer">Copyright © 2017 Liam Docherty's Site. All rights reserved.</h1>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your links to link to an `id`, not a class. Added an ID for your 3 sections that matches the section number, and updated your links to reference those ID's. You can keep the existing classes on the sections. Also made the `#contact-me` change on `.section3` while keeping `.section3` in that element's class list.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #4D5061;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #4D5061;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.nav.navbar-nav,
.nav.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#logo {
  padding-top: 2vh;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 95vh;
}

.section1 {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.section2 {
  //height: 95vh;
  background-color: #A59E8C;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.section3 {
  //height: 95vh;
  background-color: #A59E8C;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.fa-angle-down {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.fa-angle-up {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.footer {
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: #4D5061;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0:
}

h1 {
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Your Brand Name"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<section id="section1" class="section1">
  <div class="hero"></div>


  <a href="#section2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

</section>
<section id="section2" class="section2">


  <a href="#contact-me"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

</section>

<section id="contact-me" class="contact_section section3">

  <a href="#section1"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

</section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

<footer>
  <div class="page">
    <h1 class="footer">Copyright © 2017 Liam Docherty's Site. All rights reserved.</h1>
  </div>
</footer>
```